# calling ruby method also export csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
def first
  @distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["lifecycle_state = ?","closed"]).last
  @results = @distribution_sheet.results
  @specimens = @distribution_sheet.specimens
end

include DisplayResultHelper
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      @results.first.each do |res|
        send_data(
          generate_csv([
            ["Lab No","Assay","Batch","Cuttoff"],
            [res.lab_id, res.kit, res.batch_number, res.cutoff]
          ]),
          :filename => "my_data-#{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.csv",
          :type => 'text/csv'
        )
```

Is it not right to call the method `first` like this: `@results.first.each do |res|...` as above? This gives the error msg: `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!`

The purpose of this code is to export results to csv format.

Answer (score 1):

Either `@results` or `first` is `nil`. please check to make sure those are populated.